# PHP from external anchor to internal

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-mobile

I have modified my project into a one page website type.

Part of the code is this:

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= $total_pages; $i++)
{                                    
    echo '<a href="view.php?page='.$i.'" data-role="button">'.$i.'</a>';

}
```

I need that code above to work with an internal link for example:

From here:

```
echo '<a href="view.php?page='.$i.'" data-role="button">'.$i.'</a>';
```

TO

```
echo '<a href="#my-anchor?page='.$i.'" data-role="button">'.$i.'</a>';
```

Here is the full source code:

```
$per_page = 6;
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mytable ORDER BY date DESC");
$total_results = mysql_num_rows($result);
$total_pages = ceil($total_results / $per_page);

if (isset($_GET['page']) && is_numeric($_GET['page']))
{
   $show_page = $_GET['page'];    
   if ($show_page > 0 && $show_page <= $total_pages)
   {
        $start = ($show_page -1) * $per_page;
        $end = $start + $per_page;
   }
   else
   {
        // error - show first set of results
        $start = 0;
        $end = $per_page;
   }                  
}
else
{
   // if page isn't set, show first set of results
      $start = 0;
      $end = $per_page;
}

// display pagination    
echo '<strong>View Page:</strong> ';
echo '<div data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">';
for ($i = 1; $i <= $total_pages; $i++)
{          
     echo '<a href="view.php?page='.$i.'" data-role="button">'.$i.'</a>';
     //echo '<a href="#view-pag-events" data-role="button">'.$i.'</a>';                
}    
echo '</div>';
```

I need to change this:

```
echo '<a href="view.php?page='.$i.'" data-role="button">'.$i.'</a>';
```

so it's internal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: This can't be done in PHP alone. You will need send AJAX requests to a PHP script that grabs the data.

Basically, this will involve creating some javascript that listens for any changes to the hash (that's the part after the #);

```
(function(window) {
    var hash = window.location.hash;
    setTimeout(function() {
        if(window.location.hash !== hash) {
            hash = window.location.hash;
            //Grab and update page with ajax...
        }
        setTimeout(arguments.callee, 50);
    }, 50);
})(window);
```

For AJAX basics, check [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp). And please, please [respect the back button](http://www.contentwithstyle.co.uk/content/fixing-the-back-button-and-enabling-bookmarking-for-ajax-apps).

Answer (score 0):

Without reloading the page:

```
<a href="#my-anchor">foo</a>
```

If you modify the query string in the link, the page will reload and jump to the anchor:

```
<a href="?foo=bar#my-anchor">foo</a>
```

Or with JQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
   window.location.hash = 'my-anchor';
});
</script>
```